# Activity and Service: on swipe behavior

Tags: android, xamarin, android-activity, android-service

I develop a StepCounter application with Xamarin.Android.
What do I have for now:

1) In MainActivity in `OnCreate()` I call 
`StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(MyService)));` 
Then in `OnStart()` I call `BindService(serviceIntent, MyServiceConnection, Bind.AutoCreate);` 
2) That gives me a nice service which is 1) foreground 2) both StartService and BindService 3) returns `StartCommandResult.Sticky` in `OnStartCommand()` 
3) In MyService I register MainActivity as a listener for every detected step. I use Interface as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47827843/9039879) and the UI in MainActivity updates in real time, everything works perfect.

But there is a problem. 
When I swipe MainActivity from recent tasks my app supposed to shut down/finish/going off and so it does. 
But MyService is STICKY so it starts again and the user can see a notification in status bar. That's exactly what I want. Sticky undying service.
 
And than **first scenario**: user presses the notification -> that creates an activity -> `OnStart()` provides binding to MyService again -> works ok. 
**Second scenario**: user does not press the notification -> no activity has been created (it's the only service) -> user makes some steps -> application fails.

I don't know how to handle this second kind of behavior. 
Maybe that is because I register MainActivity as a listener? And if I destroy it there is nothing to update My service? In `OnStop()` I call `UnbindService(MyService);` and I expect that MyService can work even without activity. But obviously, I do something wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

UPD: Find the solution, see my answer below.

Comment: Hi, do you want to create a service which will not die even though the app has been killed?

Comment: Joe, hi!
Well, I've already have it, my service is undestroyable. But when my activity is removed, service still works and it supposed to update the activity which had been destroyed.
I was told to check listener for 'null' and I think that would help me.

Comment: So, have you solved your problem?

Comment: I'll update my question after testing the idea about listener and null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for help everyone!
 The solution was quite simple. In MyService I register MainActivity as a listener using interface. So it's not surprising that destroying activity causes failure - there is nothing to update anymore. 
Solution is check for null before calling `this.listener.UpdateUI();`

Comment: Hi,  what is your minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion? Because the STICKY not work on my phone, I need use other way to keep the service alive. And what phone are you using?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Joe! 
My phone is Digma VOX S502F, minSdkVersion is Android 5.0 and targetSdkVersion is latest Android 8.0 Oreo.
Speaking about STICKY. I looked through [link](https://github.com/MikeCodesDotNet/My-StepCounter) StepCounter by James Montemagno and see what is written in his Service:
`Workaround as on Android 4.4.2 START_STICKY has currently no effect  -> restart service every 60 mins
alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.Rtc, Java.Lang.JavaSystem
    .CurrentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60, stepIntent);`

Comment: My service is foreground also, maybe that is why STICKY does work.

Comment: Ok, I think it is the device's problem, START_STICKY can't work on my phone.

Comment: Well people who are testing my application say it doesn't restarts at all, but on my phone it does, so the device itself can cause some problems, I think.

Comment: That's why I ask you "do you want to create a service which will not die even though the app has been killed?".I have tested it, in some devices, START_STICKY won't work, because the manufacturer banned it.

Comment: Android is fragmented, so sometimes you have to integrate a lot of things to accomplish one thing.

Comment: True, and now I have another problem in my app which is about memory leak while step counting. And that causes the restart of my service. Hope, I'll can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I understood your situation and somehow also got the idea that you want to achieve.

In the service class the return type you must be using is START_STICKY and I suggest you to use START_NOT_STICKY.

Both have their own significance and use. Further how to use the return type you can go through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093271/start-sticky-and-start-not-sticky)

Comment: Pranay, thanks for your comment, but that's not what I need. You see, STICKY is exactly what I want, cause if somehow my app would be killed I want it started again and continued to count steps.
But I'll read your link more thoroughly, may be I'll find the answer.